# How to keep the display when keyboard appears on mobile web devices?

Tags: html, css

I want to create website on mobile device, and then i got some problems
On the input elements, when click the input and the keyboard appears,the display immediately change

How to keep the display when the keyboard active?
[before the keyboard active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TTTt.png)

[keyboard active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8c4X.png)

i've tried some css position but, nothing happens

Comment: is there any chance your styling is relying on `vh` (viewport height)? maybe that's the reason why your layout screws up when the keyboard is shown? or maybe you have a layer positioned the `sticky` or `fixed` way? I see it based on the second screenshot

Comment: thanks man, its worked, i'm relying on viewport heigh